# Finding the elements in $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2+2i)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am having some confusion with finding the distinct cosets in $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2+2i)$.

Attempt: Since $2+2i +(2+2i)=0+(2+2i)$ we can treat the coset representative $2+2i=0 \implies 2i=-2 \implies i=-1$ since cancellation is possible in an integral domain. Thus each element in $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2+2i)$ can be written in the form $a+(2+2i)$ for some $a \in\{0,1\}$.

Comment: I realize this is incorrect, but do not understand where my approach goes wrong. I believe it is in the cancellation part. However I though cancellation was possible so we can cancel the $2$'s since $\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain. What is going on here? What would be the correct way to approach this problem? I know there should be $8$ elements in this ring, however my approach suggests incorrectly that there are only $2$.

Edit: Now I tried this, but still know it is wrong, what is the correct way to do this?

I was thinking $2i=-2 \implies 4=-4 \implies 8=0$ so that the ring is given by $\{I,1+I,2+I,3+I,4+I,...,7+I\}$, however I do not think this is correct. What is wrong with this approach?

Edit: I found an answer somewhere where they said the ring is given by $\{a+bi+(2+2i)|a \in \{0,1,2,3\},b \in\{0,1\}\}$ can someone please help show how to arrive at this answer?

Comment: I am not seeing the reason why you wrote “Thus each element in $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2+2i)$ can be written in the form $a+(2+2i)$ for some $a \in\{0,1\}$” from “ $i=-1$”.Even if it is right why did you write that? Also, how did you get “$4=-4$” from “$2i=-2$”? Anyway, you could use the divison in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$..

Answer (score 1):

You're not using cancellation in $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, you're trying to use cancellation in $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2 + 2i)$. (Indeed, note that $2i + 2 = 0$ is false in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$; it's a true equation only in the quotient ring.) How do you know that this quotient ring is an integral domain? You can't use cancellation if you don't know you're working with an integral domain (or at least that the element you're cancelling is a non-zero-divisor).

Comment: So you cannot use cancellation but you can do all the other operations? Like square both sides?

Comment: I was thinking $2i=-2 \implies 4=-4 \implies 8=0$ so that the ring is given by $\{I,1+I,2+I,3+I,4+I,...,7+I\}$, however I do not think this is correct. What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: Keep in mind why cancellation works in integral domains: if $xy = xz$, then $x(y - z) = 0$. If you're working in an integral domain, then this means either $x = 0$ or $y - z = 0$. But if you're not in an integral domain, this doesn't have to be the case. (For example, in $\mathbb{Z}/(6)$, we have $2 \cdot 3 = 0$, but neither $2 = 0$ nor $3 = 0$.)